# Laravel + Twilio SDK: Class 'Services_Twilio_Twiml' not found

Tags: laravel, twilio

I new to *Laravel* and newer to *Twilio*.
I have a working laravel 5.4 server installed w/ Composer. I installed  the Twilio SDK in the root directory of my Twilio project w/ Composer.

I receive the following error when loading some basic code from the "Getting Started with Twilio and the Laravel framework for PHP" tutorial.

> Class 'Services_Twilio_Twiml' not found

I really don't know what to do now.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
Route::match(array('GET', 'POST'), '/incoming', function()
{
$twiml = new Services_Twilio_Twiml();
$twiml->say('Hello - your app just answered the phone.
Neat, eh?', array('voice' => 'alice'));
$response = Response::make($twiml, 200);
$response->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
return $response;
});
```

Comment: Have you ran `composer dumpautoload` after installing the SDK? Also, `php artisan cache:clear`.

Comment: Please post more code - it's impossible without seeing more of what you are doing... Otherwise people will just be wildly guessing

Comment: I added the code to my original post.                                                         I ran composer dumpautoload and php artisan cache:clear. However, the  issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think you're trying to call the old version of the [Twilio PHP library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php) there.

To use TwiML with version 5 of the PHP library you would use the `Twilio\Twiml` object, like this:

```
Route::match(array('GET', 'POST'), '/incoming', function()
{
  $twiml = new Twilio\Twiml;
  $twiml->say('Hello - your app just answered the phone.
    Neat, eh?', array('voice' => 'alice'));
  $response = Response::make($twiml, 200);
  $response->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
  return $response;
});
```

There are a bunch of [Twilio and Laravel tutorials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials?order_by=-popularity_rank&filter-product=voice&filter-language=php) available here that might help you too.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: That did help. Thank you so much for your insight.

Comment: Cool, do you mind marking the answer as correct so that other people can see it helped too? Thanks!